# How can i filter products in a category using color,price and manufacturer in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, products, filter

I have tried using a single attribute filter and i got it but when applying multiple attributes i am not getting the response.please find the below code that i tried by using multiple attribute.

```
public function getfilterproducts()
{

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            //============load category object============//
    $categoryid = 7;
    $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
    $categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');     
    $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryid);
    $productItems = $category->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setPageSize(20);


    $filter_arr = array(
        array('attribute'=> 'mobile_color','eq' => "57"),
        array('attribute'=> 'manufacturer','eq' => "65"),


        );
    $productItems = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter($filter_arr);
        // $productItems->setPageSize(20);

    $productItems->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

    foreach ($productItems as $product) {
        echo $product->getName()."</br>";


    }     
}
```

Comment: Have you confirm that you pass proper attribute code and value? And also can you tell me what output you getting from above code?

Comment: I am not getting any response from the above code...but when i am passing a single attribute like this  array('attribute'=> 'mobile_color','eq' => "57") i am getting the product details.

Comment: @christy check if you have product for the filtered attribute combination?

Comment: @Piyush yes i have checked ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
//============load category object============//
$categoryid = 7;
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryid);
$productItems = $category->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('mobile_color', 57)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 65)
    ->setPageSize(20);

foreach ($productItems as $product) {
    echo $product->getName()."==";
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any response..